# Get correct timestamp for 45 seconds ago

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, 64-bit

I am trying to get a valid MongoDB Timestamp, I have this:

```
import {Timestamp} from "bson";
const ts = Timestamp.fromInt(Date.now() - 45000);
console.log(ts);
```

that logs:

```
Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 853265937, high_: 0 }
```

that doesn't seem right, what am I doing wrong?

Note that a valid timestamp instance is a 64bit thing:
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/Timestamp.html

Comment: Have you tried `const ts = + new Date() - 45000`?

Comment: haven't tried that, what does that do?

Comment: It gets the correct timestamp for 45 seconds ago.

Comment: I don't think so - it's the same value - `const ts = Timestamp.fromInt(Date.now() - 45000);
const ts2 = Timestamp.fromInt( + new Date() - 45000);
console.log(ts);
console.log(ts2);`

Comment: the Timestamp for BSON is 64bit, I think the `Date.now()` is 32bit

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/Timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

To get Timestamp 45 seconds ago:

```
Timestamp((new Date().getTime()-45000)/1000,0)
```

Date().getTime() gives milliseconds from UNIX epoc, so that's why it's divided with 1000. Then that other parameter (0) is just zero milliseconds after that seconds value what we put to the first parameter.

Of course, if you need exact Timestamp() value, you fill that decimal part of `(new Date().getTime()-45000)/1000` as second parameter.

```
var x=(new Date().getTime()-45000)/1000; 
var y=Math.floor(x); 
var z=Math.round((x-y)*1000); 
Timestamp(y,z)
```